# Creating an automatic div with from info

Tags: php, html, css, coordinates

I need to display individual MYSQL entries on my homepage. Each entry displayed should be style-able and searchable from my homepage.

Each entry that's displayed should have a random placement on the page (Page scrollable horizontally)

I was thinking of doing it with coordinates but i am still new at this and way above my knowledge base.

I found a Solution for the echo of entries but cant get them individual styled.

Here is the link and code below

Link: [Sample](http://www.ourdevspot.com/step/)

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="id_display">
<?
 require "config"; // database connection is here

 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE");

 //fetch the results / convert results into an array

 while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

 $name = $rows['name'];
$last_name = $rows['last_name'];
$state = $rows['state'];
$email = $rows['email'];

echo '<div class="display">';
echo "$name $last_name<br>$state<br><br><br>";
echo '</div>';


}
?>
</div><!--end id display-->
</div><!--endwrapper-->
```

Comment: I have edited my question. I do appologise

Comment: Please, add the code as `code`, not an image of code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, Lets first get you through the logic. Here is client(customer computer)
Form:
Detail_1
Detail_2
Detail_3
submit button

Now when the submit button is pressed it takes these details and send it to server(for now server is simply your computer). This operation is performed by making AJAX call using javascript.

Now on server these details are retrived(php language) and stored into database(MySQL) in the table having some column names(eg "name", "age", "sex") and a row is appended from details submitted by client.

Now next step you want to show these details on homepage. This is done using calling server again using another function so that it gives all the details from our MySQL table and send these to client . Now client using these details create multiple div's for each badge again using javascript(use d3 plugin).

Do these things and you will be able to search once you learn above things using simillar procedure ie. getting text from input field sending it to server, searching in table, returning with the matched details and make a corresponding div.

Comment: Wow this helps a lot thank you for breaking it down this will help me break it into stages and then combining it at the end.